# Anonymous function in php is not working with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've created an anonymous function inside my method, it is just returning an item if the `deleted field` is equal to `0`. But the problem is it is still returning an item even if the item's `deleted` field in the database is equal to 1. Please see my code below: **Note:** This is working with `topics` only but not the rest.

```
$undeleted = function($query){
            return $query->where('deleted', 0);
};

$course = Course::with([
    'assignments' => $undeleted,
    'quizzes' => $undeleted,
    'add_links' => $undeleted,
    'topics' => $undeleted
])->findOrFail($id);
$course_items = collect($course->assignments);
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->quizzes));
$course_items = $course_items->merge(collect($course->add_links));
$course_items = $course_items->sortBy('item_number');
```

**Update:** 
*Schema*

```
Schema::create('topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->text('body');
    $table->tinyInteger('deleted');
    $table->tinyInteger('hidden');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

*Relationships*

**Course model:**
I only used `belongsToMany` with `assignments`, `quizzes`, `add_links`, and `topics` and just adding `withPivot`(*all the fields*) and `withTimestamps`. I've also added the `deleted` in the fillable attribute.

Comment: If this is working for `topics`, can you share schema for topic and the rest of the relationships?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Please see the update.